# memoir and parallel: too much blank facing pages before \chapter; no valid headings

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters, parallel

My test document:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parallel}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Single Lipsum}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{Parallel}[p]{}{}
\ParallelLText{
        \chapter{Left Lipsum}
        \lipsum[4-14]
        \vfill
}
\ParallelRText{
        \chapter{Right Lipsum}
        \lipsum[15-25]
        \vfill
}
\end{Parallel}

\chapter{Final Lipsum}
\lipsum[46-50]

\pagebreak
\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Here I have two problems:

1. There are two blank facing pages pairs (sorry for my english) before `Parallel` section.
2. `\chapter`'s in `Parallel` do not update heading lines: I have "CHAPTER 1: SINGLE LIPSUM" up to "Final Lipsum".

How can I workaround that?

Comment: The same thing happens with the `book` class so I guess that it is a problem with the `parallel' package itself rather than a combination of the `memoir` class and the `parallel` package. I have never looked at the `parallel` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for this document I will switch from `memoir` to `article` and use `\section`'s.

Now I can not see any other option .(